# Uso de parâmetro callback em funções JS

Tags: javascript, parâmetros

Estou tentando usar um parâmetro *callback* (não sei se é o termo correto aqui) dentro do meu construtor, que chama uma função q eu defini, mas toda vez q eu tento executar o código ele me apresenta um erro no console.

#### Aqui esta o código do construtor do botão:

```
function Botao(x, y, w, h, canvas, callback,color) {
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.w = w;
this.h = h;
this.cb = callback;
this.color = color;   

//render do botão.
this.render = function () {
 canvas.context.fillStyle = color || '#000'; // cor
 canvas.rect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h); // cria o retangulo(botão)
}

// verifica se o click foi na área do botao.
this.ontarget = function (pos) {      
 if (pos.x > this.x && pos.x < (this.x + this.w) && pos.y > this.y && pos.y <   (this.y + this.h)){
  this.cb(); // <-- meu problema/duvida!
  };  
}
```

#### e aqui o codigo onde eu utilizo ele:

```
var teste = new Canvas(400,300,teste, 0); // cria o canvas


var bt1 = new Botao(100,100,100,100, teste, function()  {console.log("teste");}); //cria o botao



function run() {
teste.upC();//renderiza o botão

bt1.render();// renderiza o botao.
window.requestAnimationFrame(run);
}
run();


function click(evt) {
 var rectNav = teste.rectNav; ; //obtêm as coordenadas do mouse na janela do   cliente.
 var pos = {
  x: evt.clientX - rectNav.left,
  y: evt.clientY - rectNav.top
 }; 

 bt1.ontarget(pos); //detecta se o click foi no botão 
}  


cEvent('click', click);
```

como deu para ver, se trata de um botão, onde ao clicar nele ele deve retornar a função que atribui ao *callback* na hora em que o criei, mas não consigo fazê-lo funcionar, estou usando o parâmetro de forma incorreta? A função não vai funcionar neste caso do construtor?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JScheuermann/4hkb9xus/ aqui está o codigo junto com o construtor de canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou juntar algumas correções. Podes [ver o diff aqui](https://www.diffchecker.com/yygjpbct).

No teu código no jsFiddle tens um erro de sintaxe, falta um `}`, depois usei

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('click', click.bind(this))
```

para procurar cliques. Usei `.bid(this)` para poderes usar o `this` dentro de `function click(evt) {`.

Passei uma *string* aqui `var teste = new Canvas(400, 300, 'minhaID', 0);` que no exemplo estava como variável não declarada.

E por fim comentei `//cEvent('click', click);` que no jsFiddle não estava defenido e estava a dar erro.

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

Um botão é um **componente UI** de sua aplicação, seu estilo (Visual) no que se refere **posição, dimensões, etc...** Não deve estar na **camada de comportamento**, no caso Javascript.

Quer **desenhar um botão use CSS**, "quer poupar linha de código" **use classe para componentizar** e gerar quantas **instâncias for preciso** para gerar outros, se for o caso **use o bootstrap.** ("como você enfatizou poupar tempo!!").

**Dica:** use Canvas (HTML5) para desenhar elementos que sejam dinâmicos e não botões componentes fixo de sua interface!!

**Qual seria sua dúvida:**

Callback e funções?
Desenhar elementos usando canvas com o js?
Sobre eventos no javascript?